# Vue.js: vue-alert component not rendering

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

```
import VueAlert from 'archer-vue-alert';
Vue.use(VueAlert); 

this.$alert({
  title: 'alertTitle',
  message: 'alertMessage', //message accepts string and raw_html
  confirmTxt: 'confirm btn txt' //default is 'OK'
}).then(function () {
  //...
})
```

I am sure that there is no problem with `archer-vue-alert` package, in fact, I used `vue-alert` package as well. Same problem. Why is the alert never displayed?

My package.json file:

```
"archer-vue-alert": "^2.0.2",
"onsenui": "^2.5.1",
"vue": "^2.4.2",
"vue-i18n": "^7.1.1",
"vue-infinite-scroll": "^2.0.1",
"vue-onsenui": "^2.1.0",
"vue-resource": "^1.3.4",
"vue-router": "^2.7.0",
"vuex": "^2.3.1"
```

Comment: Is this script example all in the same file? `this` needs to be a Vue instance

Comment: @thanksd yes, in the same file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your example, it looks like you are registering `VueAlert` as a plugin and then immediately attempting to display an alert by calling `$alert()` on `this` in the context of your main.js file.

Based on the [archer-vue-alert package's README](https://github.com/QingchengFED/archer-vue-alert), `$alert()` should be called on a Vue instance.

Here's one example of correct usage:

```
import VueAlert from 'archer-vue-alert';
Vue.use(VueAlert); 

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  created() {
    this.$alert({
      title: 'alertTitle',
      message: 'alertMessage',
      confirmTxt: 'confirm btn txt'
    })
  }
})
```